# Enforce generic type return function

Tags: typescript, generics

For the sake of the example, let's say I want to write a function that adds logging to any function that returns a Promise. In JS I would do something like:

```
const addLogging = (f) => (...args) => (
  f(...args).then(result => {
    console.log('result:', result);
    return result;
  })
)

const test = addLogging(
  (value) => Promise.resolve(value)
)

test('foo') // logs "​​​​​result: foo​​​​​"
```

Now I'd like to enforce typings with typescript. Here is what I came up with:

```
const addLogging = <F extends Function>(f: F): F => (
  (
    (...args: any[]) => (
      (f as any)(...args).then((result: any) => {
        console.log('result:', result);
        return result;
      })
    )
  ) as any
);

// Cool! :)
// type of test is (value: string) => Promise<string>
const test = addLogging(
  (value: string) => Promise.resolve(value),
);

// Less Cool :(
// Not valid, how to prevent it with typings?
const test2 = addLogging(
  (value: string) => value, // should return a promise
);
```

The typing of the augmented function is preserved which is nice. But first I have to use a lot of `any` and also i'd like to enforce that `addLogging`'s `f` argument must be a function that returns a `Promise`. Is there any simple way to do that with typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be more specific about your constraint on `F`, you can specify that is a function that takes any number of parameters and returns a `Promise<any>`

```
const addLogging = <F extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>(f: F) => ((
  (...args) =>
    f(...args).then((result: any) => {
      console.log('result:', result);
      return result;
    })
) as F);

//Ok
const test = addLogging(
    (value: string) => Promise.resolve(value),
);

//Error
const test2 = addLogging(
    (value: string) => value, // should return a promise
);
```

Comment: I tried something similar but I was missing the `(...args: any[])` in the generics. Thanks!